# How to make filtration query fast in my C# code with MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using this query in my C# code with MySQL database engine.
This query filter record from 8000 to 9000 and take time 10 to 14 minutes.
Can I reduce this time in my query? I am using Linq to SQL.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["FilterReport"]))    
    Listquests = Listquests.Where(q => q.Reports.Any(r => r.ReportType.Id == int.Parse(Request["FilterReport"].Split('-')[0]) && r.Language.Id == int.Parse(Request["FilterReport"].Split('-')[1]))).ToList();
    Listquests = Listquests.OrderByDescending(q => q.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: Move the int.Parse calls outside the Linq statement, along with the string.splits inside. But if you want the "best" performance I would suggest trying a direct SQL query instead of Linq, which returns all rows then does manipulations. SQL engines are designed to do very well at that stuff.

Comment: Can you give me time of response for select all rows from Listquests table `Listquests.ToList();` and from reports `Reports.Where(r => r.ReportType.Id == reportId && r.Language.Id == languageId)).Select(r => r.Id).ToList();` ?

Comment: it take time on the query as                                                                                                     ' Listquests = Listquests.Where(q => q.Reports.Any(r => r.ReportType.Id == int.Parse(Request["FilterReport"].Split('-')[0]) && r.Language.Id == int.Parse(Request["FilterReport"].Split('-')[1]))).ToList();   '

Comment: What @MarcinJ is asking is for you to give us the amount of time it takes to just pull in all of the records in Listquests.  That will give us an idea of whether or not the filter is taking up all of the time or if it's a matter of pulling in so many records.  So, again... who long does it take to just perform the `Listquest.ToList()` operation??  And the same goes for the second operation: `Reports.Where(r => r.ReportType.Id == reportId && r.Language.Id == languageId)).Select(r => r.Id).ToList()`;

Comment: @Russ exacly. My guess is joining Report in this way can cause a problem,  and response to this question will give me more clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like the following:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["FilterReport"]))   
{
       string[] reportInfo = Request["FilterReport"].Split('-');
       int reportId = int.Parse(reportInfo[0]);
       int languageId = int.Parse(reportInfo[1]);
       Listquests = Listquests.Where(q => q.Reports.Any(r => r.ReportType.Id == reportId && r.Language.Id == languageId)).OrderByDescending(q => q.Date).ToList();
}
```

It's only calling "ToList()" once, and it's also pre-defining the reportId and languageIds, however I don't think the pre-definition makes a difference, as both your example and imin it will get compiled to similar IL eventually.  The "ToList()" being called only once should help a little, though.

Comment: thanks for response but it work same as like my query.it take  time more than 15 minute to filter record ......@Russ Wilson

Answer (score 0):

This could much faster if there could be some relationship b/w Listquests & its navigational collection of Reports by having a join or group.